# PHP のセッションID に、独自の文字列を付加したい

Tags: php, sessionid

PHP のセッションID に独自の文字列を付加したいと思っています。

> **例）**
>   *PHP が生成した元のセッションID が `eyJpdiI6Im05eWNZd2Q4dVwvbjlPc3I1S` であれば、`xx-` を付加して `xx-eyJpdiI6Im05eWNZd2Q4dVwvbjlPc3I1S` としたい。*

この目的のためにいくつかのセッション関連の関数を調べましたが、

1. `session_regenerate_id()` は、新しいセッションIDを指定できないため NG
2. `session_id()` は、`session_start() の前に呼ぶ必要があるため、現在のセッションID がわからずNG

となりだめそうです。`SessionHandler::create_sid` で自前でセッションID を作る方法は、残念ながら利用している PHP のバージョンが合わず使えません。何かいいアイデアがありますでしょうか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

一度セッションを開始してセッション ID を取得し、その後、一度セッションを破棄してから セッション ID を指定してセッションを開始する事で、お望みの動作が可能かと思います。

例えば、以下の様に行います。

```php
<?php

define('SESSION_PREFIX', 'xx-');

session_start(); // セッションを開始
$sid = session_id(); // セッション ID を取得

// セッション ID が SESSION_PREFIX で始まってなければ
if (strpos($sid, SESSION_PREFIX) !== 0) {
    // session クッキーを削除
    $params = session_get_cookie_params();
    setcookie(session_name(), '', time() - 42000,
        $params['path'], $params['domain'],
        $params['secure'], $params['httponly']
    );

    // セッションデータのバックアップ
    $sessionData = $_SESSION;
    // セッションを破棄
    session_destroy();

    // SESSION_PREFIX を付与してセッションIDを指定
    $sid = SESSION_PREFIX . $sid;
    session_id($sid);

    // セッションの再開
    session_start();
    // セッションデータのリストア
    $_SESSION = $sessionData;
}

$_SESSION['val'] = !isset($_SESSION['val']) ? 0 : $_SESSION['val'] + 1;
```

なお、自前でセッション ID を生成するには、以下の方法を用いることで暗号学的に安全な ID を生成できます。

### `openssl_random_pseudo_bytes()` 関数

```php
$id = bin2hex(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(16));
```

[PHPマニュアル: openssl_random_pseudo_bytes](http://php.net/openssl_random_pseudo_bytes)

### /dev/urandom

Unix 系 OS では、乱数を生成する擬似デバイスからIDを生成できます。

```php
$id = bin2hex(file_get_contents('/dev/urandom', false, null, 0, 16));
```

[Wikipedia: /dev/random](http://ja.wikipedia.org/?title=/dev/random)

Comment: hexstring 以外に base64 や base64url が広く使われます。base64 のほうが hexstring よりも多くの種類の文字が使えるので、同じ文字数であれば、base64 のほうが予測がむずかしくなります。逆に言えば、同じ強度を実現するのにより短い文字数ですむので、結果として、通信量もより少なくてすみます。base64url の実装は Symfony の UriSafeTokenGenerator や  password_hash のソルト生成の例で見ることができます。http://security.stackexchange.com/a/39476/17924

Answer (score 0):

SessionHandler::create_sidは5.4以降でしか利用できませんが、
古くからあるsession_set_save_handler関数を利用して、
セッションID生成時に任意の関数を設定出来ると思いますので、
そちらを利用すると出来るのではないでしょうか

http://php.net/manual/ja/function.session-set-save-handler.php